# Parent div's height setting interferes with child div's float

Tags: css, html, height, css-float

I have some troubble with a web page I'm making...

I have a div that contains all elements on the page (or rather all elements between the header and the footer of the page, but that's irrelevant). The height of the body div changes due to the content it's holding.
The wrapper holds one div with id="content" that is supposed to hold whatever content I want displayed on the page, one div I use as a button (id="collapse") and one div (id="calendar") that creates a field that will hold a list of events comming up.

CSS:

```
#body {
    height:500px;
    min-height:250px;
    width:100%;
    background:#fc0;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    margin-bottom:-100%;
}
#calendar {
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    border-left:10px solid #678DC0;
    background:#b0c4de;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    margin-bottom:-100%;
}
#collapse {
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background:#678DC0;
    border-top-left-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:25px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
    border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
}
#content {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    background:#b0c4de;
    text-align:center;
    padding:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
<div id="calendar"></div>
<div id="collapse">>></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Now this is my problem: If I set #body height:auto; the float of the #collapse div and the width of the #content div acts wierd. #collapse div floats all the way to the edge of the #body div instead of stopping when it floats into the #calendar div. Same thing with the #content div. It stretches till the #body edge, not till the #calendar.

Hope I've given you a proper formulation. Any questions of what I'm asking for?

Any ideas?

Comment: When you use float, it will float the next sibling elements unless you have a Clear:both|left|right; as a css style. Because your "body" div has height:auto;, it will grow / shrink based on the sizes of the child divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ryan commented you can use the clear style to properly position your floated elements. I set up a test page here: http://jsbin.com/apinuj/2/edit#html,live, demonstrating how to use the clear fix on your html so that the body div is properly aligned when set to `height: auto.`

Comment: Thank you very mouch! Typical good answer! :)
But I'm confused about one thing... What about the line that says
`article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }`
I know what display:block does, but what did you assign it to?

Comment: Oh, don't worry about that. That's code created by jsbin. Basically its making it so that html5 tags like nav, section, etc. work in IE. Here's some info on that: [http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/)

Comment: Ehm, this is kind of wierd...
I didn't get it to work on my computer, so I started to look for differences between what I've coded and what you gave me. I didn't find anything. Than I copypasted everything from my files to that live editor. That works. But, and this is the wierd part, if I press "Render" it doesn't line up as I want. If I press "Code" it does. WTF. HELP!
http://jsbin.com/apinuj/4

Comment: Hmm, not sure. When I get some time I'll look over it.

Comment: It seems the html has issues with the calendar div being empty. I added a space to it and it now floats correctly: [http://jsbin.com/apinuj/6/](http://jsbin.com/apinuj/6/). As for the height of the page not being the same that can be modified by changing the min-height of the container.